# Match two tables with query with different parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

**A**

| id |
| --- |
| 1234-campaign=main&content=video&keyword=man |
| 4321-campaign=cast&source=youtube |

And **B:**

| row_id | campaign | content | keyword | source | clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | main | video | man | undefined | 124 |
| 4321 | cast | undefined | undefined | youtube | 10 |
| 5312 | cast | undefined | undefined | undefined | 9999 |

I want to build dynamic query to find stat in table B for rows in table A.
So for first row it should be like:

```
SELECT 
sum(clicks) as clicks, row_id, campaign, content, keyword
FROM B
WHERE row_id = 1234 AND campaign = 'main' and content = 'video' and keyword = 'man'
GROUP BY row_id, campaign, content, keyword
```

And for second row:

```
SELECT 
sum(clicks) as clicks, row_id, campaign, source
FROM B
WHERE row_id = 4321 AND campaign = 'cast' and source = 'youtube'
GROUP BY row_id, campaign, source
```

So.. I want to build a result view for all rows in table A. I need to find and return result from table B for ids in table A, but id is complex, and first I need to parse id somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you store multiple pieces of information in a single column in table A ? The application that does the INSERT on this table, should parse the content and store the result in the different columns.

Comment: You can use any programming language to read the data from the database and build the queries. Just choose your favourite language for the purpose.

Comment: Is rowID unique in table B? If so, those filters on campaign and source are unnecessary and you can simplify your query a lot by just extracting the integer before the hyphen (split_part()) and join. If it's not and those filters are meaningful you'll need to store which campaign/source are applicable for which id somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Convert things to `jsonb` and use the `@>` (contains) operator:

```
select *
  from b
       join a
         on to_jsonb(b)||jsonb_build_object('text_row_id', b.row_id::text)
              @> jsonb_object(
                             regexp_split_to_array(
                               'text_row_id-'||a.id, '[-&=]'
                             )
                           );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69d7e43b16c3a60ff57f5ae2e5eb03a5)*

Comment: That's impressive.

Comment: Nice solution but doesn't aggregate(sum) clicks.

Answer (score -1):

It could be done like this:

```
select sum(clicks) as clicks, row_id, campaign, content, keyword
from B inner join A
on (b.row_id = split_part(a.id,'-',1)::integer  
and b.campaign = split_part(split_part(a.id,'campaign=',2),'&',1))
group by row_id, campaign, content, keyword, "source";
```

attending to comments another solution would be "deactivating optional parameters" when not present, only valid for type text fields, however could be redundant with grouping sentence:

```
select sum(clicks) as clicks, row_id, campaign, content, keyword
from B inner join A on (b.row_id = split_part(a.id,'-',1)::integer  
and b.campaign = split_part(split_part(a.id,'campaign=',2),'&',1)
and b."content" ~~ coalesce (nullif(split_part(split_part(a.id,'content=',2),'&',1),''),'%' )
and b.keyword ~~ coalesce (nullif(split_part(split_part(a.id,'keyword=',2),'&',1),''),'%' )
and b."source" ~~ coalesce (nullif(split_part(split_part(a.id,'source=',2),'&',1),''),'%' ))
group by row_id, campaign, content, keyword, "source";
```

Comment: joins are around for 30 years, so you should use them

Comment: The query is a good idea, for as we know the table's columns, we don't need a dynamic query here, but only a query with optional criteria. There are little flaws in your query though. The criteria must be combined with `AND`, not `OR`. And it must be optional. One way: `WHERE row_id = split_part(a.id,'-',1)::integer  
AND campaign = COALESCE(NULLIF(split_part(split_part(a.id,'campaign=',2),'&',1), ''), campaign) AND keyword = ...`